# Active learning for Computer Vision where I have to generate my own images

Tags: machine-learning, inference, modeling, computer-vision, active-learning

I'm interested in applying active learning to a computer vision bounding box prediction project, where I don't have a large corpus of unlabeled images available, and instead have to take all pictures myself with a camera.

Usually the active learning / uncertainty sampling approach would be to take a bunch of unlabeled data points, run model inference on them, and select the items that the model is least certain about. However, in my case I don't have access to *any* unlabeled images unless I take them myself with a camera, which is costly (time consuming).

What are some good approaches to take here? I was thinking I could first roughly map out a feature space of images (e.g. background setting, number of objects, distance from camera, lighting conditions) and collect an initial random dataset that I label and train a model on. I could then just look at what images the model incorrectly classifies, and simply try to take more similar images. Is there anything wrong with this approach?

I'm hesitant because normally active learning relies on the uncertainty scores, but in my case getting unlabeled images itself comes at a high cost, so I don't have the luxury to get model predictions for a large dataset and run inference on them.

I'm also concerned that just generating more and more of the images that the model has a hard time with will eventually get me "stuck" because some configurations are just always going to be inherently hard for the model, no matter how much data I generate. I can see a scenario where my approach would tell me to keep collecting darker and darker images, until it's just a black image with no visibility, because those will always be the images that give me 0 accuracy.